# Is the syntax rule actually correct or possible?

Tags: c, syntax

I came across this post and it the second half is stumping me. I doesn't seem to be semantically correct at all. How is that even feasible. I've found out that this is not C, but C++. So, is this valid C++?

Use of Conditional Operator
We mostly use it in the following form:

```
x = (y < 0) ? 10 : 20;
```

But it could also be used as:

```
(y < 0 ? x : y) = 20;
```

Can some explain this to me please?

Comment: It is not valid for C. (Valid in C++)

Comment: This doesn't compile for me with gcc, but it does with g++. This is C++, not C.

Comment: Well the post where it was found listed it as C.

Comment: Whoever listed it as C was also confused.

Comment: You can achieve the same effect in C by doing `*(y < 0 ? &x : &y) = 20;` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why do we need to use references, and why won't it work without using references?

Comment: @agentNil these are pointers. In C the result of `?:` is never an lvalue, however C++ added a rule that if the 2nd and 3rd operand are both lvalues of the same type then the result is an lvalue.  There's no particular reason I'm aware of that C couldn't have used that rule; just that whoever wrote the standard decided not to put it in.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So the pointers are rvalues then, right?

Comment: "I doesn't seem to be semantically correct at all. How is that even feasible." -- It would help if you tried to justify such statements, because that line of code *seems* to have an obvious meaning. C just doesn't support it. "Well the post where it was found listed it as C." -- Perhaps, but without linking to it there's no particular reason to believe that.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-features-of-C-programming-which-people-dont-know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements are not meant to be equivalent. The second statement does not have a 10 in it because it's not supposed to; we're selecting a variable to assign to, rather than a value to assign to the variable.

Also, that's not C. C doesn't allow assignments like the second snippet; that's C++.